# Is "What are some current buzzwords when you go to a job interview nowadays" considered an on-topic question?

Tags: support, specific-question

"What are some current buzzwords when you go to a job interview nowadays?"

Some of these were my buzzwords, where I had to know the concepts rather than show actual code:

- LDAP
- book "Clean code" (Bob Martin)
- failovers
- spring boot LWJGL ähs
  websockets pusha annoteringsdrivet patterns validering med google
  programvara CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) metor.js löser
  synkproble, frontend test framework: phantom, karma, jasmin JMeter
  Sonar jenkins fluentenium S.O.L.I.D. JPA, hibernate CQRS
  feature-toggling DDD - domain-driven design Immutable interfaces
  event sourcing JDBC template JREbel ehcache transactions dependency
  injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Answer (score 1):

No, for several reasons:

1. It is career advice, which is specifically off-topic.
2. It asks for a list of things, which makes the question too broad.
3. It doesn't have anything to do with software design.

Comment: Do I see a list of points here? Where's the "flag as too broad" for answers? Is P.SE *only* about design (hint: no) ? My mummy used to tell me "If you have more than one reason, then none of them are valid". Sorry Robert, it's not about you, but rather this site's incapacity to let a few slightly-less-than-on-topic questions pass through (y'know, those we tag [OT] in mailing lists). On another hand, the question as formulated really sucks - that is IMHO the only reason why it can't be asked :p